# Help required in logic

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a below requirement.

I am validating one of my code-file using one utility in shell script and writing that Error,Warning messages to an output file.

Now i need to write a logic like if i have a any Error messages in that file then i need to display message saying "Please do the consistency check" and come out from the code.Else it need to continue and execute the next steps.

Comment: One cannot conclude what you want from what you have posted. Please edit your question.

Comment: You can't have an `else` after a `fi` but other than that, can you describe what it is you would like to have happen?

Comment: Thanks Eric for prompt response.Am validating my code and getting that results in a text file,Now i want to check if i have any errors in the text file then i want to exit from the script if i don't find any errors i want to continue  with other steps.

Comment: Always double-quote those $-variables unless you have an explicit good reason not to. It'll be more efficient that way and it'll save you headaches due to unintended splitting and globbing.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're asking, even after your comment above.  You'll need to re-edit your question when you can, explaining what you're trying to achieve and including any error messages you're getting.  We're making assumptions, but to get a good quality answer, you need to improve the quality of your query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Please let me know if it is clear now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a wild guess

```
if  grep ERRORS: $Sample_$DT.txt 
then
   echo "Errors found in the text file ($Sample_$DT.txt)"
else
    ## processing if no error
fi

## always processed after.
```

note also that

- I have inverted grep's argument, in the old time pattern of `grep` were before files arguement.
- it is best to put condition immediatly after `if`
- `grep` will show error (if any) before shell `echo` , use `grep -q` to avoid output.